# how to display value data from bean to radio button jsf

Tags: jsf, xhtml

Is it possible to display values from my bean to radio button in the view?

I'm using jsf.

```
<h:outputLabel value="Gender"/>
                        <h:selectOneRadio value="#{ctrlLogin.session.gender}" readonly="true">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="Male" itemLabel="Male" itemDisabled="true" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="Female" itemLabel="Female" itemDisabled="true"/>
                </h:selectOneRadio>
```

i already have a user bean that carries the actual value from the database

Comment: Do you mean _reading_ values of JSF radio button's labels from bean ? If so, edit your question by adding the relative code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible. I assume that you have some kind of list in a bean? You really should provide some code. Anyway, the solution below should give you an idea how to populate radio buttons with values.

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="radio"
                      value="#{bean.selectedOption}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listOfOptions}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item}" itemValue="#{item}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```